# Inheritance in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a template method that should be executed a certain other method is called.
For example:

```
func main(){
   onInit()
}

func onInit(){
   var Instance entity.EntityInstance
   Instance.Init()
   //do something
}
```

Another source file, instance.go

```
type EntityInstance struct{
   name string
   version string
}
func (instance *EntityInstance) Init(){
// do some initialization
}
```

The main method is in different code base/app and uses the Instance app to invoke certain initializations.
Currently the user writing this above main method needs to explicitly call the Instance.init()

The objective is for the developers (in this case one who implements the main method) only concern themselves with any of their custom initializations and not worry about calling "Instance.Init()". The OnInit() invoke should take care of "Instance.Init()" implicitly.

Any help to get me started in the right direction ?

**EDIT**: I do understand that the exact OOP concepts cannot be translated here in Golang but all I'm looking for is the appropriate approach. Clearly, I need to change the way I think of design in here but just don't know how.

Comment: First of all, Go does not have the concepts of classes and inheritance like traditional OO languages (although there are features that provide some similar functionality). As for initialization, are you talking about initialization of a particular instance of a type or initialization of a package? The normal pattern in Go for creating an object that requires some initialization is to define a method that returns a pointer to an initialized object. if you need to do some initialization in a package (i.e., only once), you can do that with an `init` function.

Comment: Indeed, there is no inheritance in Go, and there are no abstract classes either. This question doesn't make any sense as written.

Comment: I understand that the exact translation from java (oop) concepts isn't possible but I'm looking for a way that can make some implicit method calls like I mentioned, with a preference of not changing the design too much as it's an existing prod code.

Comment: I'm certainly a go neophyte but I can tell you, from 30+ years of experience, that if your goal is to keep the same design while changing paradigms that you'll suffer greatly.  The point of a language change is to reap the benefits of that (new) language.  If you insist on retaining the old ways you should question 'why change at all?'

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, I suspect because you are trying to directly translate ideas and idioms from another language, you should resist doing that. However, if you want an implicit init for a package in Go, you can use the magic function name

```
func init(){}
```

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init

> Finally, each source file can define its own niladic init function to
>   set up whatever state is required. (Actually each file can have
>   multiple init functions.) And finally means finally: init is called
>   after all the variable declarations in the package have evaluated
>   their initializers, and those are evaluated only after all the
>   imported packages have been initialized.

Be careful with this though, it is implicit behaviour and could cause mysterious bugs if your callers don't know it is happening when they import your package.

Comment: Not really exact translation. I only stated what should've done in the OOP language but I'm trying to figure what's the approach in Golang,and which do I even begin to get that done.
Regarding using init(), my concern is that's an extra implementation that has to taken care by the main method user. I'll probably rephrase few things and add bunch of details.

Comment: Init doesn't need to be taken care of in main it can be in any file or pkg, read that entire linked page as it may help with other things too if new to go.